# Consultation about dynamically add to array

Tags: java, android

how to add unknow numbers of colors to this array ? for example i whant to add 6 colors

```
int[] colors = new int[] { Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN };
```

and how to add unknow numbers of categorySeries ? for example i want to add 6 categorySeries

```
CategorySeries categorySeries = new CategorySeries("Vehicles Chart");
categorySeries.add("cars ", 30);
categorySeries.add("trucks", 20);
categorySeries.add("bikes ", 60);
categorySeries.add("plan ", 40);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add unknown numbers of items to an array, because arrays can't resize.

Use an `ArrayList` instead:

```
List<CategorySeries> categorySeriess = new ArrayList<CategorySeries>();
CategorySeries categorySeries = new CategorySeries("Vehicles Chart");
categorySeries.add("cars ", 30);
categorySeries.add("trucks", 20);
categorySeries.add("bikes ", 60);
categorySeries.add("plan ", 40);
categorySeriess.add(categorySeries);
```

And for the colors:

```
List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
colors.add(Color.RED);  // single add
colors.addAll(Arrays.asList(Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN));  // bulk add
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), using it's `add` method and then calling `toArray` on it. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many items you want to keep track of, an array is probably not the best choice of data structure. I would recommend a linked list.

Check out `java.util.LinkedList`.  You can use generic types to specify which kind of elements it should hold.

For example,

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        ll.push(1);
        ll.push(2);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could make the `CategorySeries` linked list with `LinkedList<CategorySeries> ll = new LinkedList<CategorySeries>()`.